# Trying to connect to Cassandra in a managed bean. Getting a incompatible guava error

Tags: java, cassandra, primefaces, guava, managed-bean

```
@Named(value = "glicoseChart")
@Dependent
public class GlicoseChart implements Serializable{

private LineChartModel glicoseModel;
public LongTermPersistence longTerm;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    createLineModels();
}

public LineChartModel getGlicoseModel() {
    return glicoseModel;
}

private void createLineModels() {     
    glicoseModel = initLinearModel();
}

private LineChartModel initLinearModel() 
{
    LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();

    longTerm = new LongTermPersistence();

    // VVVVVVVVVVVVV
    longTerm.connectB();
```

It gives an error trying to connect.
And the connection code:

```
 public void connectB()
 {
   this.cluster = Cluster.builder()
           .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
           .withPort(9042)
           .build();
   session = cluster.connect();

}
```

It gives an error trying to build the cluster.
However, if I try to connect in another class, and not in the managed bean, it works just fine.

However, inside the managed bean, i get this error:

> Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverInternalError: Detected incompatible version of Guava in the classpath. You need 16.0.1 or higher.
>   at com.datastax.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility.selectImplementation(GuavaCompatibility.java:138)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.GuavaCompatibility.(GuavaCompatibility.java:52)

The thing is, i'm using guava-19.0, and it's saying im using 16 below, which is not true, since I can use that piece of code in another class' main. I'm using cassandra 3 btw.

Comment: Check your dependencies. If you are using maven, use `mvn dependency:tree`. Probably one of your dependencies is pulling in older version of guava.

Comment: I tried that, but there was only one version of guava being used, and it was the version 19. So I'm at a loss

Comment: How and where do you deploy your managed bean?

Comment: <p:chart type="line" model="#{glicoseChart.glicoseModel}" style="height:400px;"/>